# How to count total of ints in a list?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, class, listbox

I am trying to combine all the ints in a list into one total amount (the total price). However I am using 2 radiobuttons to decide the price that gets added to a list and listbox, and when switching between the two buttons my total amount gets ruined.

I am using a class to separate my input (name and price), this gives me a RideNamePrice.Price, which gets added to the list. I am using that list as a source to populate my listbox. See code below.

```
lbjourney.itemSource = finishedRide;
        List<RideInput> FinishedRide= new List<RideInput>();     

double totalprice = 0;
foreach (var item in lbjourney.Items)
        {
            totalprice = totalprice+ 
             Convert.ToDouble(RideNamePrice.Price);
        }
listboxTotal.content = totalprice;
```

When i add 3 prices with the first radiobutton it works great, but if i decide to add one price from the second radiobutton it adds about 3 times the amount of the number that's supposed to be added.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, it is not possible to help you.

Comment: As per this statement "I am trying to combine all the ints in a list into one total amount (the total price)." - I cannot see in your code that you were using any item in your foreach loop to sum the ints of a list. Can you provide some more code.

Comment: Obvious things to check: You're looping 3 times somehow. You have 3 times the items in your list.  You're not resetting totalprice back to zero.

Comment: @GK edited my post